# full hidden input via jquery and catch them in my controller

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm using symfony to get value from another page via jquery.

My form:

```
$builder
                ->add('dateChoisie', 'hidden', array('attr' => array('class' => 'dateChoisieCache')))
                ->add('secteur', 'hidden', array('attr' => array('class' => 'secteurCache')))
                ->add('ajouterCont', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success')))
                ->add('quant', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        '1' => '1',
                        '2' => '2',
                        '3' => '3',
                        '4' => '4',
                        '5' => '5',
                        '6' => '6',
                        '7' => '7',
                        '8' => '8',
                        '9' => '9',
                        '10' => '10',
                        '11' => '11',
                        '12' => '12'
                    ),
                    'preferred_choices' => array('1'),
        ));
    }
```

In my view:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.secteur) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.quant, {'label': "Quantités"}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.ajouterCont, {'label': "Ajouter et continuer les achats"}) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Then I full my hidden fields via jquery:

```
$(".dateChoisieCache").text(dateChoisie);
$(".secteurCache").text(secteur);
```

Then I send the form. I can catch the quant input, but not the others one hidden, full by jquery.

```
$quatités = $form->getData()['quant'];
$date = $form->getData()['dateChoisie'];
$secteur = $form->getData()['secteur'];
```

Anybody knows why?

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: Can you use the text jQuery function to set a field? Try using this instead: $(".dateChoisieCache").val(dateChoisie);

Comment: Also use Chromes network inspector to see if the fields are being populated correctly.

Comment: http://puu.sh/iIyrz/8f5bf15209.png 

In the inspect, it seems to work. And I have changed this to val and it's the same.

Comment: Guess the next step would be to check the values on the server. Debug or output the $_REQUEST and $form->getData() values to make sure then values have been submitted correctly. They should be in $_REQUEST[{FormName}]['dataChoisie'] and in the same array structure for $form->getData()